# Creating a ribbon button to open a browser link

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm looking to create a ribbon button for an OL2k10 add-in that opens a specific website.  I've only seen [references](http://blog.iphelion.com/post/2011/02/04/Launching-Outlook-Internal-Web-Browser-In-Code.aspx) to creating a button using CommandBars, but this is different that what I'd like to accomplish.

Ideas are welcome as usual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think here is what you probably can do:

In your ribbon button click event function, you write the following code which would allow you do launch a web browser accessing the given URL, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com

```
string myURL = "http://stackoverflow.com";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myURL);
```

Okay, I guess that's pretty much all you need. :)